# Python Pandas Dataframe to Nested Tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a simple Pandas data frame (df), structured like this:

```
   a   b   c   d
0  WW  XX  YY  ZZ
1  AA  BB  CC  DD
2  EE  FF  GG  HH
3       ...
```

I'd like to get this into a nested tuple structure inside of a list that looks like this:

```
[ ((WW, XX), YY, ZZ), ((AA, BB), CC, DD), ((EE, FF), GG, HH) ... ]
```

I'm just starting Python/Pandas, so I'm not really sure how to go about this.

Comment: this works for your dataset but is this really your dataset though as it's not dynamic: `[((l[0], l[1]), l[2], l[3]) for l in df.values.tolist()]`

Comment: Yeah, that's the format of the dataset at least.  The actual values are larger than what I said here, but the format is the same.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a dataframe like this:

```
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  6  7  8
```

You can get the raw values into a list form like this:

```
>>> t = df.values.tolist()
>>> t
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8]]
```

from there you can transform it into your tuples like so:

```
>>> tt= tuple(((a,b), c) for a,b,c in t)
>>> tt
(((1, 2), 3), ((4, 5), 6), ((6, 7), 8))
```